# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower' when saying nothing in voice assistant

Tags: python, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, pyttsx3

I am making a voice assistant in python but when i dont speak in it i get a error like this:

Sorry, I could not Understand You!
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "g:\Python\app.py", line 47, in 
query = sptext().lower()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'``

Here is the code:

```
def sptext():
    recognizer=sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening to You....")
        recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, 2.5)
        recognizer.pause_threshold = 1
        audio=recognizer.listen(source, timeout=5, phrase_time_limit=8)
        try:
            print("Processing your voice...")
            data=recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
            print(data)
            return data
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("Sorry, I could not Understand You!")
        

def speak(text):
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
    engine.setProperty('voice',voices[1].id)
    rate = engine.getProperty('rate')
    engine.setProperty('rate',120)
    engine.say(text)
    print(text)
    engine.runAndWait()



if __name__ == '__main__':

    while True:

        query = sptext().lower()

        if "hello" in query:
            speak("Hi, how are you?")
```

Answer (score 2):

so what is the expected output, when you speak nothing. Either it should go to time out exception. I think it is already going to except inside sptext method. You need to explicitly either return some static text once it goes to except. Added one return statement in your sptext method. hope that works for you instead of erroring out your code as sptext doesn't return any text when it goes to except

```
def sptext():
    recognizer=sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening to You....")
        recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, 2.5)
        recognizer.pause_threshold = 1
        audio=recognizer.listen(source, timeout=5, phrase_time_limit=8)
        try:
            print("Processing your voice...")
            data=recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
            print(data)
            return data
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("Sorry, I could not Understand You!")
            return ''
```